# Создал файл с функциями и тест к нему обращается. Падает. почему?

Tags: python, selenium

Создал файл core.py

Собрал туда класс, функции, методы. вот:

```
from _pytest import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class EO(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\drivers\\chromedriver')
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    def test_eo(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('.......')

    def tear_down(self):
        self.driver.quit()
```

Вот сам тест:

```
import core

core.self.driver.find_element_by_id('').send_keys('')
core.self.driver.find_element_by_id('').send_keys('')
core.self.driver.find_element_by_id('......').click()
```

Это кусок кода. но рабочий, при условии, что все в одном файле. Почему падает?

Comment: Каким образом падает?

Comment: Хотя сразу же очевидно, что переменной `core.self` не существует

Comment: @ andreymal Убрать self?

Comment: Почитать в любом учебнике, что такое классы

Comment: У вас как-то все перепутано, "обычный" код пытается обратиться к данным из тестирующего класса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тест падает скорее всего потому, что неправильно перегружен метод `tearDown` (у вас он называется `tear_down`). Еще атрибут `self.driver` не объявлен в классе.

```
class EO(unittest.TestCase):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\drivers\\chromedriver')
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    def test_eo(self):
        self.driver.get('.......')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
```

В самом тесте нужно обращаться вот так:

```
from core import EO

EO.driver.find_element_by_id('').send_keys('')
EO.driver.find_element_by_id('').send_keys('')
EO.driver.find_element_by_id('......').click()
```

Comment: Спасибо. За ответ. А, если несколько тестов обращаются к этому файлу?

Comment: @СергейБогданов всё тоже самое. Будет круто, если отметите галочкой этот пост как ответ.